# Receiving messages when deleting a record

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Here is my function to delete a record from a table.

```
async deleteTodo(id: number) {
    this.todosRepository.delete(id);
}
```

How do I properly receive messages while deleting?

For example, when a user sends an identifier for a record that is not there, I want to receive the message "record not found" or when an error occurs while deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.delete` does not check if the entity exist in the database](http://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html).

If you want to properly check whether or not your record exists or not, you can `select` them and check the returned value.

Example:

```
const model = await this.todosRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("todos")
  .where('todos.id= :todelid', { id: todelid })
  .getOne();

if (model.length == 0) {
  return "No record found.";
} else {
  return "Record found.";
}
```